# Ошибка при вставке строки

Tags: python, sqlite, telebot

создал функцию для быстрой вставки в таблицу

`c.execute(f'INSERT INTO westusers VALUES(id = {ida}, name = {namea}, username = {usernamea}, mail = {maila}, status = {statusa}, main = {maina}, uunique = {uuniquea}, donatebalance = {donatebalancea})')`

использую

`westadduser(ida = message.from_user.id, namea = message.from_user.username, usernamea = message.from_user.username)`

выдает ошибку что нет таких колонок (id, name...)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А так пробовали? `f'INSERT INTO westusers (id, name, username, mail, status, main, uunique, donatebalance) VALUES({ida}, {namea}, {usernamea}, {maila}, {statusa}, {maina}, {uuniquea}, {donatebalancea})'`

Comment: теперь считает namea за название колонки